# Android Fused Location API Location Not Accurate

Tags: android, gps, fusedlocationproviderapi, android-fusedlocation

I am using Fused Location API for one of my app. I have set the priority to LocationRequest.PRIORITY_HIGH_ACCURACY. When I set interval/fastest interval to few milli seconds, what I observe is that GPS is on all the time and I get Lat Lng with accuracy of around 4m but when I set the interval to say around 10 minutes I observe that GPS is off for 10 minutes and after that, before GPS indicator is still stable I get the location with the accuracy of 1km. Can anyone please explain this behaviour and what I am doing wrong?

Comment: Look at the Google documentation regarding location. By only getting a single location with large time interval I would suggest creating an alarmmanager or similar. Then every x minutes sample the fused locations for a 5-10 seconds and pick the best (the one with lowest accuracy value). Otherwise you risk getting location based on GSM or WiFi, the first being very inaccurate.